# Use result from SQL query in different table

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have three different tables like this

```
table_1

Field 1: victories
Field 2: name

table_2

Field 1: name
Field 2: birthday
```

Now I would want to get the birthday of the person with the most victories.

So I would do something like this (pseudo code):

```
select victories from table_1 and sum_it_all
get name and pass name to table_2
select birthday from table_2 where name
```

Ok, this is pretty ugly pseudo code, but I hope you get the point.

Using Andomar's solution works fine.
Now I tried to nest another table in it, like this though:

```
select address
from table_3
where birthday = 
    (
    select  birthday
    from    table_2
    where   name = 
            (
            select  name
            from    table_1
            group by
                name
            order by
                sum(victories) desc
            limit   1
            )
    )
```

I do get a correct answer, but for some reason also get a `null` back. And how would I output the sum of victories?

Comment: What is your question on this?
this is looking like you have answer of your question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  birthday
from    table_2 t2
where   name = 
        (
        select  name
        from    table_1 t1
        order by
                victories desc
        limit   1
        )
```

If one user can have multiple rows in `table_1`, you'd have to `sum` the victories:

```
select  birthday
from    table_2 t2
where   name = 
        (
        select  name
        from    table_1 t1
        group by
                name
        order by
                sum(victories) desc
        limit   1
        )
```

Comment: where are the victories summed?

Comment: This answer assumes a 1:1 relation between `table_1` and `table_2`.  I'll add a version for a 1:many relation

Comment: Thanks. It works for two tables. Can you take a look at my initial post again?

Comment: Brian Driscoll's answer will print the sum of victories.  As for the `null`, check the content of `table_3` ?  Does it contain `null` address for the top name?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT t2.name, SUM(t1.victories) as SumOfVictories, t2.birthday 
FROM table_1 as t1
JOIN table_2 as t2
ON table_1.name = table_2.name
GROUP BY t2.name, t2.birthday
ORDER BY SUM(t1.victories) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Good answer. +1 from me. I'm deleting mine out of a clear misunderstanding of the OP request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following nested SQL:

```
 select name, birthday from table_2 where name in (
   select name from table_1 order by victories desc limit 1
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.name=table_2.name ORDER BY victories DESC` give you the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution for your problem:

```
SELECT table_1.name, table_2.birthday
FROM table_2
JOIN table_1 ON table_1.name=table_2.name
WHERE table_1.victories>=ALL(SELECT table_1.victories
                             FROM table_1)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
   Select name, birthday from table_2 t2
       Join table_1 t1 On t1.Name = t2.name
   Having Count(*) = 
         (Select Max(namCount)
          From (Select Count(*) namCount
                From table_1
                Group By name))
   Group By t1.name
```

Comment: I don't think you can nest aggregates like `max(count(*))` ?

Comment: correct,  I omitted second subquery when I transcribed concept from brain to website!